# Get count of members of an active directory group?

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to get a count of members that belong to a specific group based on the OU? When I run the code below it is giving me the value of 3 for each OU when there is only 1 OU that has a value of 3, the rest should be 0. It is running the Get-ADGroupMember -Identity “Test_Group”).count against the whole active directory structure instead of just for each OU??

```
import-module activedirectory
foreach ($ou in  Get-ADOrganizationalUnit  -filter * -SearchScope 1){

 $computers = 0 + (get-adcomputer -filter * -searchbase $ou.distinguishedname).count    


 $ou | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name Computers -value $computers -force 


 Foreach ($Member in  $ou){

 (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity “Test_Group”).count 

 }

 $ou | select name,computers 

}
```

Comment: Your foreach loop doesn't make any sense. You are running a command which is always going to return the same result multiple times and has nothing to do with the variables used to establish the foreach loop.

Comment: I am not sure what else I would do then? Sorry I am new to powershell

Comment: It's ok. Well you would just remove the nested foreach loop ($Member in $Ou) and take the portion from that script block and put it outside of the main foreach loop since there is no point in repeatedly running it. A better way to go about doing this would be to get the group membership first which gives you the DN of each member, so you can then filter the ones not matching the OU you care about and count what is left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My interpetation of your question is that for a paricular AD Group you are looking for a member count based on OU or container.

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "insert_your_group" -Recursive | 
        Where-Object{$_.objectClass -eq "User"} |
        Get-ADUser -Properties canonicalname | 
        Select-Object @{Name='Container';Expression={$_.canonicalname | split-path -parent}} |
        Group-Object container |
        Select Name,Count
```

Breaking this down line by line

1. Grab all member of a particular group as well including members of other groups.
2. Ensure we are only processing users and not the group themselves. We already have all the users from the `-Recursive` so they can be ignored.
3. Get all the user objects with a Get-ADUser call. We need the `canonicalname` as that is we get the information for the parent container
4. Here is the fun part. Using the `canonicalname` split it up (like you would a directory) and just take the `-parent` portion.
5. Group the objects in order to get the count you are looking for
6. Simplify output with a select statment.

**Output**

```
Name                                                                    Count
----                                                                    -----
Domain.Local\OU\SubOU                                                   8
Domain.Local\OU\SubOU2                                                  8
Domain.Local\OU\SubOU5                                                  2
```

Answer (score 1):

(Get-ADGroupMember 'AD-groupname' -Recursive).count